# CakeEmail how to determine failure before stack trace?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to catch when an email fails so that I can save the required data in my database and I can attempt to send at a later date.

I thought the following should work as it does when using `save()`

```
        if ( $email->send() ) {
            //..success - works..
        } else {
            //..fail - never gets here, stack trace
        }
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xY8rq.png]

Comment: it doesn't work? Because $email->send() return true or false, have you tried to comment that line? To check if te error is there?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri well the true part works, but in the case of timing out a stack trace is called before `send()` returns false which, could have something to do with debug mode, `throw new SocketException(__d('cake_dev', 'Unable to connect to SMTP server.'));`

Comment: Nope even with `Configure::write('debug', 0);` it still will drop an internal error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

obviously you are not in debug mode there.
if you were, you would see that this actually throws an exception.

and you are catching sth there, just not the exception thrown :)

try this:

```
try {
    $success = $email->send();
    ...
} catch (SocketException $e) { // Exception would be too generic, so use SocketException here
    $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
    ...
}
```

this way you can catch the exception and do sth here.