# CakePHP emails suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I have been using CakePHP's email class for close to a year now. The system has been sending html emails without problems. Two days ago I received reports that customers were not receiving their notifications. I noticed as well that I wasn't receiving my admin notifications.

My first thought was something changed with my server (hosted by GoDaddy). I do not believe it is my hosting provider as I have tested a php's raw mail() function and even sent a quick text email through CakePHP's class. I also tested each debug mode and error logs, nothing to indicate an error occurred. Here is the code I have been using (successfully) since a couple days ago. This code is the same around 10 times throughout my app.

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->template('order_status_change', 'default')
->emailFormat('html')
->to($order['Order']['email'])
->subject('blah blah ' . $order['Order']['id'] . ' status change: ' . $status['Status']['label'])
->from(array('myemail@gmail.com' => 'blah blah'))
->viewVars(array(
    'id' => $order['Order']['id'],
    'firstName' => $order['Order']['first_name'],
    'statusLabel' => $status['Status']['label'],
    'statusDescr' => $status['Status']['description']
))
->send();
```

A couple things to note:

1. I have confirmed that the html template 'order_status_change' and
   default layout are in the correct folders (they were working before)
2. I have confirmed that the variables are all correctly set at the
   time of email

If I have to switch to text emails I will but I cannot seem to fathom how the code would suddenly stop working. The only thing I have changed is the debug mode (which I have been doing since the beginning).

**Update**

Emails stopped working again so I switched over to text mail. However for some odd reason when I put a url in the body (like http://www.google.com) the mail fails. However if I remove just the .com then it will go through. What the hell is happening?

**Update 2**

This is my current config that will send out text emails without links in them (when I say links I mean a url string)

```
class EmailConfig {

    public $godaddy = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net',
        'port' => 25,
        'timeout' => 300,
        'log' => true,
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'headerCharset' => 'utf-8'
    );

}
```

I confirmed that Go Daddy does not need authentication and the port is 25.

Comment: Please post your config (without passwords offcourse). Are you using smtp or standard mail configuration? If debug transport works it is likely in the configuration or in the connection somewhere. Please try to catch the exception, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053112/cakeemail-how-to-determine-failure-before-stack-trace

Comment: Both do not work now, SMTP using GoDaddy's relay server and standard mail using mail(). The debug info is not throwing an error and there are no entries in the CakePHP error log.

Comment: Try to run the CakePHP tests and check the CakePHP version.

Comment: At this point I do not think it is the CakePHP version. I was on version 2.3 something when it started, I updated to the latest to see if that would fix it. So now I am on 2.4.1 I believe.

Comment: Try catching the exception: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14054368/1177905 might help to see more details on the issue.